# IdentityServer4 : Service to service call fails to find Audience

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, identityserver4

I am trying to make use of IdentityServer4 for authenticating the user for a Micoservices architecture. When I am trying to make a call from my Web App controller to another Web API service, the call fails on the Web API service with the message on the console that looks like below:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException: 
IDX10214: Audience validation failed. 
Audiences: 'null/resources'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'hierarchy' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null'.
```

My chain of call is something like below:

`[User] --> [ASP.Net core MVC: Web App ]--> [ASP.Net core MVC: Web Api ]`

I have created an `Identity server` using the `IdentityServer4` with the following configuration:

**API resources**

```
new ApiResource("hierarchy", "Hierarchy Configuration API"),
new ApiResource("deviceconfiguration", "Device Configuration API"),
```

**Client**

```
new Client
{
   ClientId = "system.health.check",
   ClientName = "System health check client",
   AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

   ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },
   AllowedScopes = {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        "healthcheck"
                    },

    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5100/signin-oidc",  "http://localhost:5103/signin-oidc",},
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5100/signout-callback-oidc" },
}
```

**Service - Startup**

```
services.AddIdentityServer(x => x.IssuerUri = "null")
        .AddSigningCredential(Certificate.Certificate.Get())
        .AddTemporarySigningCredential()
        .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
        .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
        .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
        .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers());
```

**[ASP.Net core MVC: Web App ]**

I have setup my opthion as below:

```
"OpenIdConnectOptions": {
  "AuthenticationScheme": "oidc",
  "SignInScheme": "Cookies",
  "Authority": "http://localhost:5000",
  "RequireHttpsMetadata": false,
  "ClientId": "system.health.check",
  "ClientSecret": "secret",
  "ResponseType": "code id_token",
  "GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint": true,
  "SaveTokens": true
}
```

the configure code on the startup looks like this:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
     AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies"
});

var option1 = new OpenIdConnectOptions();
Configuration.GetSection("Security:OpenIdConnectOptions").Bind(option1);
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(option1);
```

This works well so far and I can see that when the user is not Authenticated, he is directed to the Identity server and the token is issues.

Now the issue is that I want call form this service to be routed to another `Web API service` that is also protected via scope of say `hierarchy` as shown below:

***Service to service call***

```
var accessToken = await HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:5103/api/Hierarchy/22");
requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken); 

var _client = new HttpClient();
var response = await _client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

**[ASP.Net core MVC: Web Api ]**

Startup is setup same as my other service but as this is a resource service my configuration is different:

```
"IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions": {
  "Authority": "http://localhost:5000",
  "RequireHttpsMetadata": false,
  "ApiName": "hierarchy",
  "AllowedScopes": [
    "openid",
    "hierarchy"
  ]
```

the configure code on the startup looks like this:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
     AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies"
});

var option2 = new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions();
Configuration.GetSection("Security:IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions").Bind(option2);
app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(option2);
```

Now the issue is that the call does not return anything and on the console of this service I see a log that says:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'null/resources'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'hierarchy' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null'.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Validators.ValidateAudience(IEnumerable`1 audiences, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateTokenPayload(JwtSecurityToken jwt, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.<HandleAuthenticateAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
```

when I decode the access token on my `[Web App]` this is what I see

```
{
  "nbf": 1501764330,
  "exp": 1501767930,
  "iss": "null",
  "aud": "null/resources",
  "client_id": "system.health.check",
  "sub": "2",
  "auth_time": 1501764327,
  "idp": "local",
  "scope": [
    "openid",
    "profile"
  ],
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ]
}
```

so its clearly missing the `Audience` as well as scope `healthcheck` 
any ideas as to why its missing the `Audience` or what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your api name is "hierarchy", try passing this in Allowed Scopes in the client configuration. Here:

```
new Client
{
   ClientId = "system.health.check",
   ClientName = "System health check client",
   AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

   ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },
   AllowedScopes = {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        "healthcheck" <------
                    },

    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5100/signin-oidc",  "http://localhost:5103/signin-oidc",},
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5100/signout-callback-oidc" },
}
```

You can add it after **healthcheck**

Comment: Any ideas how I can pass this? I don't see a place t o add allowed scopes in the client call. I am referring to the section `Service to service call` above

Comment: Thanks, Tried that, but still the same error. not sure why it says  `Audiences: 'null/resources'-`

Comment: yes, my web App uses `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(option1);` where as my Web API uses `app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(option2);` is that the problem?

Comment: no thats all fine, try decode your access token and check if you are getting any value for aud -  the audience is the sum of all possible resources. you can go to jwt.io for decoding

Comment: actually that is the issue, i see `"aud": "null/resources",` when I decode the access token. I am not able to see where to set this value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150961/discussion-between-jaydeeess-and-kiran).

Comment: Thanks @JayDeeEss for helping out. For records if some one falls in to this trap, the issue was with the `OpenIdConnectOptions` above had missed the option for scope. by adding Scope there and also the  `AllowedScopes` on the client mentioned here the issue is solved.